# Datagridview different handlers on each column

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am making a .net project on C# using a datagridview control.

My problem is that I want each column items of the datagridview to have different event handlers. How can I do that?

Please help!

Comment: Can you explain why you want a "different event handlers" on each column ? And what type of event do you want to handle ?

Comment: @Florian For example I want column 3 to be a price textbox column . So when I leave the textbox the $ symbol shows next to the value . And also on the keydown event to block non numeric values

Comment: You should handle CellLeave and KeyDown events on your datagridview then :-)

Comment: @Florian yes but I would like to have a NAME column which it would have different keydown and leave events. Thats my problem

Comment: You need to apply your events on a control, which is, in your case, your datagridview. Inside your handling function, you can create specific rules for a given column/row/etc. I created a basic example

Answer (score 0):

You want to handle two events :

**CellLeave**

**KeyDown**

When you handle  your events, you are going to use object arguments such as :

- sender (of type *Object*)
- e (of type *DataGridViewCellEventArgs* in case of CellLeave)
- e (of type *System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs* in case of KeyDown)

If you want to create specific rule for each column, you can use properties of e.

For example :

```
DataGridView1_CellLeave(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        //DoStuff when leave first datagrid's column
    }
}

DataGridView1_KeyDown(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Shift)
    {        
        //You can do stuff on DataGridView1.CurrentCell when Shift is pressed
    }
}
```